# Codeigniter 'order_by' adds ordering by 'id' automatically

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have this table:

```
LANGUAGES

ID  NAME    DEFAULT ACTIVE
1   English     0     1
2   Italian     1     1 
3   Spanish     0     1
```

The extraction order is: all the active but first the default one, then the others.
I'm using this query inside codeigniter :

```
public function get_languages_list() {

    $array = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('languages');
    $this->db->order_by('default','desc');
    $this->db->where("active",1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $array[$row->id] = array();
        $array[$row->id]["name"] = $row->name;
        $array[$row->id]["default"] = $row->default;
        $array[$row->id]["active"] = $row->active;
    }
    return $array;  

}
```

it works correctly, but only in some cases. In the others the ordering not works correctly.
i have print the queries in both cases:

**CORRECT CASE**

```
SELECT * FROM `languages` WHERE `active` = 1 ORDER BY `default` DESC
```

**STRANGE CASE**

```
SELECT * FROM `languages` WHERE `active` = 1 ORDER BY `id`, `default` DESC
```

Codeigniter adds the '`id`' in the `order_by` behaviour.
The way i call this query is always the same, there's no dynamic parameters,db records are the same for both case, anyway the resulting query is different.
I can't find anything related to this thing in codeigniter docs.
How it is possible? May it's a bug?

EDIT

now i have inserted che complete method to show that there's no parameter or particular conditions.
I have also tried this alternative in query elements order:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('languages');
$this->db->where("active",1);
$this->db->order_by('default','desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

result is the same.
I have tried to add some others condition in order_by but result is the same.

EDIT 2

my codeigniter version:

```
CI-3.1.10
```

Comment: Can you post the code blocks that call the model method?? Are you passing any parameter or any condition that is applicable while calling this method??

Comment: hi , no parameter is passed to that method. i will edit question anyway

Comment: I tried this 500 times atleast. The case didn't occur with me. I tried this on CI-3.1.9. What is yours?

Comment: thank you,my version is CI-3.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the situation that I understood from your question, that is a completely normal occurrence.

That is just the default behavior of the sorting system provided by the database. In specific case, when the data has been finished sorting by the defined attribute; in your case it is the DEFAULT attribute; then if it encounters (well almost in all real-life cases) the entries with same value from that attribute, it will check for the primary ID for the sorting. Therefore, this is the cause of why it looks like that the output of the query is incorrect.

You may try to re-arrange the code like below:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_languages');
$this->db->where("is_active",1);
$this->db->order_by('is_default','desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Notice that I only altered the position between WHERE line and the ORDER_BY line

And you may also add more specific attributes for the sorting.

However, this is only from my assumption. I think you should show us the portion of the data and the cases you had encountered in real where you found the "bug" so we can analyze deeper and further.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, i have edited my question. Anyway i have tried to change order of elements but result is the same

Comment: @user31929: it's really an interesting case, i like it. i tested using the same CI version with you too btw. how about the entries of data in that table, are those all? i mean, are you able to show the real case of the inconsistent output you got? together with the entries of data from the LANGUAGE table you have

Comment: this is the real case table, nothing more than this